# Visual studio intellisense messing up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, intellisense

So I'm new to MVC4 and C#, I have been designing this website for about 2 weeks now and there have not been any issues with the intelisense.

For 2 days now Visual studio is telling me that @Viewbag and other @ commands are not part of my project and i may be missing something or it tells me that Viewbag doesn't exist in the current context.

I'm unsure how to fix this ( i have restarted the project and the machine im working on ) still showing up underlined and tells me it doesn't exists in the context

Since I'm still new when i look / try new code this is very difficult since *everything* is wrong..

> Example Images :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
The long error you can barely read states that

> System.Web.WebPages.Html.htmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Actionlink' .... missing assembly reference ?

I get this error for any @codes in the Razor view aswell exept C# @'s

> WebConfig File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
 -->
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=ANE-SQL\ANESQLSERVER;Database=OilGas;User Id=software;Password=GLvp$102;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
 <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
 <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
 <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>

<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"></customErrors>


<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="180" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>



</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />-->
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*."   verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"   preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*."   verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"    type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"    preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory    type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
     </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Are you still able to compile and run your project?

Comment: What version and edition of Visual Studio and Windows are you using?

Comment: VS 2012 Prem , 7 Professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Internet web app take out your changes ( from the old code ) Insert the newly created Internet Web App config file, Add old changes back ( skip all the reading line by line see if any of that really was messing up )

Hope that helps

Comment: I just found out that the appSettings needs to be high up in the Web.config file, otherwise it drove Intellisense crazy. I put mine just below the <configSections> element (since that is required to be first by IIS).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have specified the Razor version you are using in the `appSettings` of your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Also make sure that your views are in their standard locations (a.k.a. the `~/Views` folder).

Comment: Changed it to the code you are showing above, did not work, even tried setting --<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />-- , no effect, all my views are in ../Views, let me post my web.config file see if you can find something that doesnt belong?

Comment: In my case changing  
`<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />` to  
`<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />`  solves the problem. On my machine VS 2015 installed and on new web projects razor intellisence worked, but on old one - not. The diffference was in web.config webpages:Version.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, after i mistakenly added `<appSettings>` into Views Web.config instead of the "main" Web.config file. Took me a few hours to figure that out...

Hope it helps someone.