# Razor editor formatting not working after installing Web Essentials and Web Compiler

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials, web-compiler

I've just rebuilt my machine with a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015. I've also installed the extensions for Web Essentials and Web Compiler but these seem to have caused a problem

Say for example, prior to installing Web Essentials and Web Compiler, if I was editing a Razor view, if the current element was formatted a couple of tabs in, and I pressed enter, the cursor would automatically tab to the correct place.

**Working Example:**

```
<ul>
    <li> <!--press enter here-->
        |<!--would put cursor here-->
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Non Working Example:**

```
<ul>
    <li> <!--press enter here-->
|<!--put's cursor here-->
    </li>
</ul>
```

This as I'm sure you can understand is quite annoying!

I'm pretty sure it's something to do with Web Essentials or Web Compiler because this wasn't a problem before-hand. In addition to this, I am getting the following error on startup:

[image: Error]

And this appears to be the culprit in ActivityLog.xml

**ERROR**
*Editor or Editor Extension*

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Item
>   has already been added. Key in dictionary:
>   'RazorSupportedRuntimeVersion' Key being added:
>   'RazorSupportedRuntimeVersion' at
>   System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean
>   add) at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value) at
>   System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary.Add(Object key, Object
>   value) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.PropertyCollection.AddProperty(Object
>   key, Object property) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Razor.RazorVersionDetector.Microsoft.Html.Editor.ContainedLanguage.Razor.Def.IRazorVersionDetector.GetVersion(ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer) at
>   Microsoft.Html.Editor.ContainedLanguage.Razor.RazorUtility.TryGetRazorVersion(ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer, Version& razorVersion) at
>   Microsoft.Html.Editor.ContainedLanguage.Razor.RazorErrorTagger..ctor(ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type,
>   Object[] args) at
>   Microsoft.Html.Editor.ContainedLanguage.Common.ContainedCodeErrorTaggerProvider`1.CreateTagger[T](ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer)

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the two extensions? Do the problems persist?  Have you tried installing only one of the two?

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam yeah tried that

Comment: And did you still have the issues?

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam I did

Comment: It would be nice to know if this problem arises with only one of the products is installed. But its tedious to do full VS uninstall and install to start from a clean slate. So I guess this question boils down to how annoying this problem is to you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 Broken Razor Intellisense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581666/visual-studio-2015-broken-razor-intellisense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happend to me today and I fix the problem following the instructions from the accepted answer to this question: [Visual Studio 2015 Broken Razor Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581666/visual-studio-2015-broken-razor-intellisense)

Here is the answer:

> I solved this problem by resetting the user data
>
> ```
> devenv.exe /resetuserdata
> ```
>
> and remove the ".vs" folder in my project.