# Keywords are not coloured in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed visual studio 2015 and created an MVC project using .net core application. But every thing is in a black font color and the keywords are not highlighted.

- Tried uninstalling DevExpress
- Tried running devenv.exe which was found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE.
- I have also visual studio 2013 installed previously with a correct coloring of key words. Tried exporting the setting from 2013 and improted it 2015 but no change at all.

But nothing helped.

Comment: Something I have noticed on the visual studio 2015 IDE I have installed, under Tools->Option ->Text Editor->CSharp->Coding styles and the rest options below it such us Formatting and IntelliSense when clicked, it says "an error occurred loading this page property".

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015 go to the Tools > Environment and change the Color them and (maybe) uncheck the box "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance". In the same windows, go to Fonts and Colors and make sure colors are set for Text Editor, for example HTML Comment should have a green Item foreground color.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it doesn't solve it. The .cs files are still all in black color.

Comment: Have you tried those stackoverflow answers  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581666/visual-studio-2015-broken-razor-intellisense/32376450#32376450 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311355/visual-studio-2015-not-syntax-highlighting-razor-nor-intellisense