# ASP.NET Core. When I make new view (.cshtml), the C# don't works

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[On image, in view vs doesn't paint code in different colors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OFAF.png)

I think that my project ASP.NET Core has broken, because when I make new view, C# don't works and i don't know what to do. And new methods in controller don't work correctly.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309817/intellisense-in-razor-files-cshtml-stopped-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581666/visual-studio-2015-broken-razor-intellisense).

Comment: Close the file and reopen it again, that usually works for me.